# Injecting multiple dao into one service

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

if I have several DAOs to be injected into a Service that need to work together in a single transaction, how can I do this ?

```
@Component
public class CallerClass{
@Autowired    
private TransactionClass1 class1;
@Autowired    
private TransactionClass2 class2;

public void saveOperation(){    
    try{
        class1.save();
        class2.save();
    }catch(Exception ex){
    }
}
}
```

Like above simple codes. However, this code is lack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just inject all the DAOs in the same manner as you do normally i.e. setter or constructor using @Inject or @Autowired.

You then annotate your service method as Transactional and invoke the required operations on the multiple DAOs. The transaction will encompass all of the dao calls within it.

```
@Transactional
public void doStuff() {
  dao1.doStuff();
  dao2.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Well, doStuff() method's class should be annotated with @Component, right ?

Comment: Yes, if you are using Autowiring to wire up your components. I guess I assumed you were. You may also be using the newer @Configuration/@Bean or just plain XMl.

Answer (score 1):

You must open the transaction before you use the first dao (For example with `@Transactional`).

```
public class MyService{

  @Inject
  Dao1 dao1;

  @Inject
  Dao2 dao2;

  @Transactional
  public doStuffInOneTransaction{
     Object x = dao1.load();
     Object y = doSomething(x);
     dao2.save(y);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use JTA? Do you implement your transactions on your own? Please provide more information about your architecture so we can respond accordingly.

EDIT:
Check this one out, for example:
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView